# ANYCHART - PERT Chart, how to add horizontal scroll

Tags: anychart

We are using Anychart Version 7.13 to create a PERT Chart in our application. Our data has a series of tasks with predecessors that require the chart to scroll horizontally. Our chart is getting truncated and we have tried to adjust chart.width in both % and PX but not able to enable horizontal scroll.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Vikas[Screenshot showing truncation on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfzJ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should adjust spacing between milestones and milestones size in %. This will allow the pert chart fitting into the stage width. I prepared a sample for you below, the chart is scrollable. Please, pay attention to CSS style, stage settings and size/spacing settings. Probably, you should try other values in % exactly for your pert chart.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  // create data
  var data = [
    {id: "1", duration: 1, name: "Task A"},
    {id: "2", duration: 3, name: "Task B", dependsOn:["1"]},
    {id: "3", duration: 4, name: "Task C", dependsOn:["2"]},
    {id: "4", duration: 1, name: "Task D", dependsOn:["3"]},
    {id: "5", duration: 2, name: "Task E", dependsOn: ["4"]},
    {id: "6", duration: 2, name: "Task F", dependsOn: ["5"]},
    {id: "7", duration: 1, name: "Task G", dependsOn: ["6"]},
    {id: "8", duration: 2, name: "Task H", dependsOn: ["7"]},
    {id: "9", duration: 3, name: "Task I", dependsOn: ["8"]},
    {id: "10", duration: 2, name: "Task J", dependsOn: ["9"]}
  ];

  // create a chart
  var chart = anychart.pert();
  //create stage
  var  stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");
  //set stage width
   stage.width(2000);
 
  // adjsut milestones size in %   
  chart.milestones().size('5%');
  //adjust spacing in %
  chart.horizontalSpacing("9%");

  // set chart data
  chart.data(data, "as-table");
  //render chart
  chart.container(stage).draw();  
});
```

```css
     html, body,   #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-pert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="container"></div>
```